# Как создать индекс включающий в себя строку при использовании Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Я использую [entity-framework](/questions/tagged/entity-framework) версии 6.1.3. Класс доменной модели выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class ReferenceBook
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    [Index("IX_ParentId_Name", IsUnique = true, Order = 1)]
    public int? ParentId {get;set;}
    [Required, Index("IX_ParentId_Name", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

При попытке выполнить миграцию полученную я получаю сообщение об ошибке:

> Тип столбца "Name" в таблице "dbo.Items" не позволяет выбрать его в качестве ключевого столбца индекса.

похожий вопрос на [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27687080/5610621)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27687080/5610621

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как оказалось данная ошибка возникает из за того что отсутствует аннотация [`StringLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute(v=vs.110).aspx).

Добавив данную аннотацию следующим образом: `[StringLength(50)]` мы тем самым ограничиваем длину столбца `Name` в таблице бд

```
[Required, Index("IX_ParentId_Name", IsUnique = true, Order = 2)]
[StringLength(50)]
public string Name {get;set;}
```

После этого миграция выполняется без проблем